# Clearing textarea on pressing enter in React, in a stateless component

Tags: reactjs

I'm building a chat component in React and can't figure out how to clear the textarea element after the enter key is pressed. The component is stateless, and there are no props associated with the textarea, so it is never re-rendered.

```
sendMessage(e) {
  if (e.key === 'Enter') {
    this.props.onKeyUp(e.target.value)
    // I want to clear the textarea around here
  }
}

render() {
  return(
  ...
  <textarea onKeyUp={this.sendMessage}></textarea>
  ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just clear the `value` of `target` after your work with value.

```
e.target.value = "";
```

Example:

```js
class Test extends React.Component {
  sendMessage(e) {
    if (e.key === 'Enter') {
      //this.props.onKeyUp(e.target.value) your work with value
      // I want to clear the textarea around here
      e.target.value = "";
    }
  }

  render() {
    return <textarea onKeyUp = {this.sendMessage}></textarea>
  }

}

ReactDOM.render(<Test/>, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Answer (score 3):

```
constructor(props){
 this.state({value:""})
}
sendMessage(e) {
  if (e.key === 'Enter') {
    this.props.onKeyUp(e.target.value)
    // I want to clear the textarea around here
    this.setState({value:""})
  }
}
handleChange=(e)=>{
  this.setState({value :e.target.value})
}
render() {
  return <textarea value={this.state.value} onChange={this.handleChange} onKeyUp = {this.sendMessage}></textarea>
}
```

Answer (score 1):

An answer that worked was deleted, basically it said to use refs: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html